# Bash: How would I remove the first part of a directory from a array for multiple files in a for loop?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, scripting, symlink

I am trying to write a script that manages dotfiles for me, and this is what I have:

```
dots=(
    ~/.config/alacritty
    ~/.config/dunst
    ~/.config/flameshot
    ~/.config/i3
    ~/.config/i3status
    ~/.config/kitty
    ~/.config/nvim
    ~/.config/picom
    ~/.config/rofi
    ~/.config/gtk-3.0
    ~/.config/obs-studio
    ~/.config/sway
    ~/.config/waybar
    ~/.config/swappy
    ~/.config/mako
    ~/.config/swaylock
    ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json
    ~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json
    ~/.config/fontconfig
    ~/.bash_logout
    ~/.bash_profile
    ~/.bashrc
    ~/.profile
    ~/.stignore
    ~/.gtkrc-2.0
)

for name in "${dots[@]}"; do
    if [ ! -e "$name" ]; then
        echo "$name does not exist."
        ln -sv "$HOME/Dotfiles/dots/${name#~/.config/}" "$name"
    else
        echo "$name exists."
    fi
done
```

The issue here is that it removes the `~/.config/` part from directories like `~/.config/sway`, but it doesn't remove the `~/` part for things like `~/.profile`.

My question is, how would I make it where it removed the `~/.config/` part and the `~/` part for files that have them?

Edit: Replaced `echo` with `ln -sv` in the symlink line. I replaced it with `echo` so that I can test if it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is, how would I make it where it removed the ~/.config/ part and the ~/ part for files that have them?

Personally, I'd do it in two steps, storing the intermediate result in a separate variable:

```
        local_part=${name#~/}
        ln -sv "$HOME/Dotfiles/dots/${local_part#.config/}" "$name"
```

Comment: Perfect! I think it's so weird how you guys can come up with solutions so easily. Thanks!